# Logcat-real object has been deleted

Tags: android, logcat

i am searching on "The real object has been deleted". but dnt find any proper solution,

on my logcat this message is shown again and again,

plz if u have proper solution of this plz help me.

```
E/webcoreglue(270):  The real object has been deleted
E/webcoreglue(270): The real object has been deleted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```